# How to call a subclass method inside an another class rather than its super class?

Tags: java, subclass

I want to call a subclass function in another class in java.How do I do this?

AS an example here is my super class and subclass.

```
public abstract class a
{
  method 0;
}

class b extends a
{
   method 1;
}
```

There is another class call `c`. I wanna do the following operation in class c. C is an another class in a new file.But in the same package.

```
class c
{
   c val;
   public c
   {
      a var1 =( (b)val.method0()).method1;

   }
}
```

but I got an exception when running the program stating that cant cast type a to type b. Does anyone have a suggestion to get rid of this?

Here is the actual exception error I got.(I wrote above code as a demonstration)

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   classfileparser.ConstantClass cannot be cast to
>   classfileparser.ConstantUtf8  at
>   classfileparser.ClassFile.(ClassFile.java:50)   at
>   classfileparser.ClassFileParser.main(ClassFileParser.java:18)
>   C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: I think you're missing some `extends` statements...

Comment: You try to cast some `c` in some `b`, which is not possible since these classes do not stand in any inheritance-relationship (especially since `b` is not a superclass of `c`).

Comment: Please follow the Java naming conventions and post compilable code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way your code looks, and since you have no restrictive modifiers in your code (unless you do) ,  all you have to do is instantiate the subclass and call it's method inside your c class.

Are these static methods ?

Comment: No they are not static methods. Can you explain how to instantiate subclass in the class c please?

Answer (score 0):

An object that is an instance of class `a` is not necessarily an instance of subclass `b`. For example, if you also have subclass `d`:

```
  a
 / \
b   d
```

An object of type `d` is not an instance of `b` and has no access to the class methods defined in `b`. The `ClassCastException` is thrown because you're trying to cast the object to something that it's not an instance of. For more details, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html.

Based on the exception message, `method0` is returning a `ConstantClass`, but you're trying to cast it to `ConstantUtf8`. You can either implement `method1` in `ConstantClass` (or a superclass) and cast to that class, or you'll have to change `method0` to return an instance of `ConstantUtf8` instead of `ConstantClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast a class c item to b which is not possible.If you want to use the methods of class a and b you should make the b superclass of c so that item of class c have access to the methods and fields of class c.
This might help you to understands classes better:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

I think what you did here is declaring another Top level class with a different name the compiler calls the *classname.java* so when you call class b its not found because compiler looks for *a.java* if thats the name of your file.You can do what you want if class b is in new *b.java* file **or** you can declare class b as an inner class instead and call it from class c like so:-

In Class a:-

```
public abstract class a
{
method 0;

class b{
method 1;
}
}
```

In Class c:-

```
class c extends a{// because a is abstract c extends a
a obj1 = new a();//obj1 of class a is declared
a.b obj2 = obj1.new b();//obj2 declared for class b through obj1

public c{
obj2.method(1);//call method in inner class b
}
```